# UFT-PERFECTO Erase existing text field value in IOS

Tags: hp-uft

I need to erase the existing value and set new value in iOS using UFT-PERFECTO. For that I used

```
Device("DUT").MNativeElement("Editbox").Set "newvalue"
```

but that command sets new value in Android (removing the existing), but in iOS it is appending. I tried using `.Set ""` but this also appending space instead removing the old entry.

How to remove the existing value in edit box and place new value?

Comment: Try `.Type` instead of `.Set`

Comment: No . It is throwing error  "Failed executing operation" when i use .Type